# Help reading orientation from gyroscope

Tags: gyroscope

I recently bought a [L3GD20H Triple-Axis Gyro](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1032) to use it to measure orientation, but found out it instead reports the **rate of rotation** in **degrees per second**. I was told this means that to detect the total degrees of rotation, I need to integrate the rate of rotation over time. 
I was wondering if someone could help me with this since I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a formula to create. here is my code so far if it helps:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_L3GD20_U.h>

/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_L3GD20_Unified gyro = Adafruit_L3GD20_Unified(20);

void displaySensorDetails(void)
{
  sensor_t sensor;
  gyro.getSensor(&sensor);
  Serial.println("------------------------------------");
  Serial.print  ("Sensor:       "); Serial.println(sensor.name);
  Serial.print  ("Driver Ver:   "); Serial.println(sensor.version);
  Serial.print  ("Unique ID:    "); Serial.println(sensor.sensor_id);
  Serial.print  ("Max Value:    "); Serial.print(sensor.max_value); Serial.println(" rad/s");
  Serial.print  ("Min Value:    "); Serial.print(sensor.min_value); Serial.println(" rad/s");
  Serial.print  ("Resolution:   "); Serial.print(sensor.resolution); Serial.println(" rad/s");  
  Serial.println("------------------------------------");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}

void setup(void) 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Gyroscope Test"); Serial.println("");

  /* Enable auto-ranging */
  gyro.enableAutoRange(true);

  /* Initialise the sensor */
  if(!gyro.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the L3GD20 ... check your connections */
    Serial.println("Ooops, no L3GD20 detected ... Check your wiring!");
    while(1);
  }

  /* Display some basic information on this sensor */
  displaySensorDetails();
}

void loop(void) 
{
  /* Get a new sensor event */ 
  sensors_event_t event; 
  gyro.getEvent(&event);

  /* Display the results (speed is measured in rad/s) */
  Serial.print("X: "); Serial.print(event.gyro.x); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("Y: "); Serial.print(event.gyro.y); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("Z: "); Serial.print(event.gyro.z); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.println("rad/s ");
  delay(1);
}
```

So in summary, I need help creating the code/a formula that will use my Gyro to measure its orientation. Thank you for your time! I'm very lost.

Comment: To “integrate” is a slight oversimplification: you will have to compose many small rotations in order to get the current orientation. You should probably search for a library that does that for you, unless you are willing to dig into the [heavy math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example.

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int MPU = 0x68; // MPU6050 I2C address
float AccX, AccY, AccZ;
float GyroX, GyroY, GyroZ;
float accAngleX, accAngleY, gyroAngleX, gyroAngleY, gyroAngleZ;
float roll, pitch, yaw;
float AccErrorX, AccErrorY, GyroErrorX, GyroErrorY, GyroErrorZ;
float elapsedTime, currentTime, previousTime;
int c = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Wire.begin();                      // Initialize comunication
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);       // Start communication with MPU6050 // MPU=0x68
  Wire.write(0x6B);                  // Talk to the register 6B
  Wire.write(0x00);                  // Make reset - place a 0 into the 6B register
  Wire.endTransmission(true);        //end the transmission
  /*
  // Configure Accelerometer Sensitivity - Full Scale Range (default +/- 2g)
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x1C);                  //Talk to the ACCEL_CONFIG register (1C hex)
  Wire.write(0x10);                  //Set the register bits as 00010000 (+/- 8g full scale range)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  // Configure Gyro Sensitivity - Full Scale Range (default +/- 250deg/s)
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x1B);                   // Talk to the GYRO_CONFIG register (1B hex)
  Wire.write(0x10);                   // Set the register bits as 00010000 (1000deg/s full scale)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  delay(20);
  */
  // Call this function if you need to get the IMU error values for your module
  calculate_IMU_error();
  delay(20);

}

void loop() {
  // === Read acceleromter data === //
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x3B); // Start with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 16384, according to the datasheet
  AccX = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0; // X-axis value
  AccY = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0; // Y-axis value
  AccZ = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0; // Z-axis value
  // Calculating Roll and Pitch from the accelerometer data
  accAngleX = (atan(AccY / sqrt(pow(AccX, 2) + pow(AccZ, 2))) * 180 / PI) - 0.58; // AccErrorX ~(0.58) See the calculate_IMU_error()custom function for more details
  accAngleY = (atan(-1 * AccX / sqrt(pow(AccY, 2) + pow(AccZ, 2))) * 180 / PI) + 1.58; // AccErrorY ~(-1.58)

  // === Read gyroscope data === //
  previousTime = currentTime;        // Previous time is stored before the actual time read
  currentTime = millis();            // Current time actual time read
  elapsedTime = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000; // Divide by 1000 to get seconds
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x43); // Gyro data first register address 0x43
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 6, true); // Read 4 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  GyroX = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 131.0; // For a 250deg/s range we have to divide first the raw value by 131.0, according to the datasheet
  GyroY = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 131.0;
  GyroZ = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 131.0;
  // Correct the outputs with the calculated error values
  GyroX = GyroX + 0.56; // GyroErrorX ~(-0.56)
  GyroY = GyroY - 2; // GyroErrorY ~(2)
  GyroZ = GyroZ + 0.79; // GyroErrorZ ~ (-0.8)

  // Currently the raw values are in degrees per seconds, deg/s, so we need to multiply by sendonds (s) to get the angle in degrees
  gyroAngleX = gyroAngleX + GyroX * elapsedTime; // deg/s * s = deg
  gyroAngleY = gyroAngleY + GyroY * elapsedTime;
  yaw =  yaw + GyroZ * elapsedTime;

  // Complementary filter - combine acceleromter and gyro angle values
  roll = 0.96 * gyroAngleX + 0.04 * accAngleX;
  pitch = 0.96 * gyroAngleY + 0.04 * accAngleY;

  // Print the values on the serial monitor
  Serial.print(roll);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(pitch);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.println(yaw);
}


void calculate_IMU_error() {
  // We can call this funtion in the setup section to calculate the accelerometer and gyro data error. From here we will get the error values used in the above equations printed on the Serial Monitor.
  // Note that we should place the IMU flat in order to get the proper values, so that we then can the correct values
  // Read accelerometer values 200 times
  while (c < 200) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
    Wire.write(0x3B);
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 6, true);
    AccX = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0 ;
    AccY = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0 ;
    AccZ = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0 ;
    // Sum all readings
    AccErrorX = AccErrorX + ((atan((AccY) / sqrt(pow((AccX), 2) + pow((AccZ), 2))) * 180 / PI));
    AccErrorY = AccErrorY + ((atan(-1 * (AccX) / sqrt(pow((AccY), 2) + pow((AccZ), 2))) * 180 / PI));
    c++;
  }
  //Divide the sum by 200 to get the error value
  AccErrorX = AccErrorX / 200;
  AccErrorY = AccErrorY / 200;
  c = 0;
  // Read gyro values 200 times
  while (c < 200) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
    Wire.write(0x43);
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 6, true);
    GyroX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    GyroY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    GyroZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    // Sum all readings
    GyroErrorX = GyroErrorX + (GyroX / 131.0);
    GyroErrorY = GyroErrorY + (GyroY / 131.0);
    GyroErrorZ = GyroErrorZ + (GyroZ / 131.0);
    c++;
  }
  //Divide the sum by 200 to get the error value
  GyroErrorX = GyroErrorX / 200;
  GyroErrorY = GyroErrorY / 200;
  GyroErrorZ = GyroErrorZ / 200;
  // Print the error values on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("AccErrorX: ");
  Serial.println(AccErrorX);
  Serial.print("AccErrorY: ");
  Serial.println(AccErrorY);
  Serial.print("GyroErrorX: ");
  Serial.println(GyroErrorX);
  Serial.print("GyroErrorY: ");
  Serial.println(GyroErrorY);
  Serial.print("GyroErrorZ: ");
  Serial.println(GyroErrorZ);
}
```

https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-mpu6050-accelerometer-and-gyroscope-tutorial/

Comment: Do not do `Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read()`: the C++ language does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the two calls to `Wire.read()`. Do `val=Wire.read()<<8;val|=Wire.read()` instead. Also, this naive integration will only work if the roll and pitch angles remain small.